# Iterate over the tokens in the doc contains a dot in front a number

Tags: tokenize, spacy

It looks like the output is not as what I expecting. Could it be by design or program bug?

```
doc = nlp(
    "Line 1 50%. "
    "Line 2 40% end space and dot ." # try comment
    # "Line 2 40% end space and dot." # try comment
    "20% at line 3 where Line 2 end with or without space"
)

# Iterate over the tokens in the doc
for token in doc:
    # Check if the token resembles a number
    if token.like_num:
        # Get the next token in the document
        next_token = doc[token.i+1]
        # Check if the next token's text equals "%"
        if next_token.text == "%":
            print("Percentage found:", token.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `doc.text` and see the reason for what you're getting:

```
doc.text
'Line 1 50%. Line 2 40% end space and dot .20% at line 3 where Line 2 end with or without space'
```

Tip: you have all your strings concatenated into one.

To achieve what you want feed your docs as comma separated strings:

```
docs = nlp.pipe(["Line 1 50%. "
                 ,"Line 2 40% end space and dot ."
                 ,"20% at line 3 where Line 2 end with or without space"])

for doc in docs:
    for token in doc:
        if token.like_num and doc[token.i+1].text=="%":
            print("Percentage found:", token)
Percentage found: 50
Percentage found: 40
Percentage found: 20
```

Comment: @Kenny Does it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers